# App Store公開用Archiveの作成方法について

Tags: macos, app-store

初めてApp Store公開用のpkgファイルを作成しているのですが、Achiveファイルの作成が出来ていません。（**一応Archiveは作成されるのですが、正しく作成されていないと思っています**）
下記の設定でArciveを作成しています。しかし、

- この設定でRunするとFinished Runとなりアプリケーションは立ち上がりません。
- ArchiveされたファイルをOrganizerでのValidateするとエラーとはならず、Valifation
  Successfulでした。
- privisioning profileをDevelopmentのMac App Development, DistributionのDeveloper IDで設定してArciveを作成し、exportしたアプリは実行可能でした。
- DistributionのMac App Storeのprivisioning profileでArchiveを作成し、それをexportしたpkgをインストールしたアプリは起動できず、アプリケーションはクラッシュします。そのときのException Typeは、EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)となっていました。
- privisioning profileの設定の変更以外の変更（ソースコードの変更）は行なっていません。

provisioning profile等のsigningの設定に不備があると考えているのですが、その不備を指摘頂けませんか。

[Xcode ver. 8.3]
(General:Signing) Debug, Release共に同一に設定しています。
Provisioning Profile: XC OSX: xxx
Team: xxx
Signing Certificate: 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: xxx

(Capabilities)
App Sandbox: ON

(Build Setting:Signing)
Code Signing Identity: Mac Distribution
Developer Team: xxx
Provisioning Profile: XC OSX: xxx

[Apple Developer]
(Provisioning Profiles)
Name: XC OSX: xxx
Type: Mac Distribution
App ID: xxx
Certificates: 1 total
Devices: 0 total
Enabled Services: In-App Purchase
Status: Active
Expires: Apr 02, 2018
Cerficates: xxx(Mac App Distribution)

[Cetificates] Xcode8.3から作成
Name: xxx
Type: Mac App Distribution
Exprires: Apr 02, 2018

また、不足している情報などありましたらお知らせ下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 何か勘違いされているように思うのですが、Archiveの動作は、App Store提出用のバイナリー(アーカイブファイル)を作成するだけですので、正常終了しても **アプリケーションは立ち上がりません** 。アーカイブファイルを作成してDeveloperポータルでそのアプリをWaiting For Uploadのステータスにしたら、あとはアップロードするだけです。

Comment: "Archive"を実行したとき、アーカイブファイルは作成されています。ですが、このまま設定を変更せず、"Run"したときにアプリケーションが立ち上がりません。これは正常な動作なのでしょうか。App Store登録用のprovisioning profileでは起動されないのでしょうか。正常だと思えなくて作成されたアーカイブファイルも正しく作成されていないのでは、と考えてるのですが

Comment: Archiveの動作とは全く別に、アプリをRunで起動して正しく起動できないのであれば、それはArchiveとは直接関係なく、アプリのデバッグが不十分である、と言うことだと思われるのですが。Archiveに至る前にそれなりのテストはされていると思うのですが、Archive用に何か特別な設定変更でもされたのでしょうか。

Comment: App Store登録用のprovisioning profileを設定し、"Archive"を作成。そのままの状態で"Run"を実行したとき、アプリケーションが立ち上がらないのは問題なさそうです。一応、審査には通ってAppStoreに登録され、ダウンロードしたアプリは起動できました。私にはprovisioning profileとその挙動の理解が足りないようです。

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。自分の過去のやり方が当たり前という前提で書いていたので、ご理解しにくいコメントになっていたかもしれません。あなたのご経験を回答の形で投稿していただくことで、他の開発者にとってもより有用な情報となるかと思いますので、できればお時間をとって回答としてご記載ください。